# Using maps over template literals

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, string, boolean

so I need to print a boolean value if the given string contains [[placeholder:var3]] but the var3 will be dynamically fed from an array as belwo:

```
const delmethod = ['all', 'email', 'sms', 'fax', 'voice', 'voicemail', 'pager', 'pagerTwoWay'];
let languages = organizationLocales.map(a => a.locale);
 let variabless = alertDetails.variables?.map(k => k.name); languages && languages.length > 0 && languages.map(lang => { delmethod.map(i => {
 if ( alertDetails.alertMessage?.[${lang}]?.[i]?.variabless?.some(el => [i] === [[placeholder:${el}]]) ) 
{ bodyContainsVariables = true; } }); })
```

I tried using map around the template literals but it is throwing me an error also tried like above eg but it checks only first value of the array, so can someone please help me solve this, I'd appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

updating the question with the actual PS. **organizationLocales** is an array and **alertDetails** is an object that has an variables array, **Delmethod** is an array is being used to check the different properties dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[[placeholder:${variabless}]]` yields `[[placeholder:var1,var2,var3]]`. It doesn't check the first variable. And that's not how `Array.string.includes` is supposed to be used. For checking exact match use the `===` operator.

In case you want to check if any of the array elements match the string you can use the `Array.prototype.some` method which returns a boolean value.

```
let any = variabless.some(el => s === `[[placeholder:${el}]]`)
```

If you want to find the element that matches with the string use the `Array.prototype.find` function.

Comment: Thanks for the help,so I attachd the my whole code belw which is suposed to chk for placeholder

 let languages = organizationLocales.map(a => a.locale);
 let variabless = alertDetails.variables?.map(k => k.name);
    languages &&
        languages.length > 0 &&
        languages.map(lang => {
            delmethod.map(i => {
                if (
                    alertDetails.alertMessage?.[`${lang}`]?.[i]?.variabless?.some(el => [i] === `[[placeholder:${el}]]`)
                ) {
                    bodyContainsVariables = true;
                }
            });
        });

Comment: It is returning false all the time, did I miss something there?

Comment: organizationLocales is an array and alertDetails is an object which has the properties of alertMessage variables and lang

Comment: You are welcome. The simple snippet that I have suggested should work. Please update your question instead of posting a wall of code in the comment section.

Comment: Appologies @Ram, I've now updated the question and when I try I'm always getting false I think the condition is not working properly, can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the index inside template literals becasue `variabless` is an array like this:

```
console.log(s.includes(`[[placeholder:${variabless[2]}]]`));
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is hardcoded value right? I’m looking for a dynamic value like it should check the array for each element whether the array element matches with the string if so return true

Answer (score 0):

you're currently passing the whole array in

`s.includes([[placeholder:${variabless}]])`

and that's won't work, you need to specify which elemnt of the variables array you want to inject to your string which is element indexed with 2 so it should be like that

`s.includes([[placeholder:${variabless[2]}]])`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is hardcoded value right? I’m looking for a dynamic value like it should check the array for each element whether the array element matches with the string if so return true

Answer (score 0):

To match against *any* value in `variabless`, you can test against a regular expression:

```js
console.log(new RegExp(
   `\\[\\[placeholder:(${variabless.join('|')})\\]\\]`
 ).test(s));
```